# Gmail Android App like ActionView/Spinner (NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST)

Tags: android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I am trying to achieve NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST like gmail Android Application.
My main issue is to hide the currently selected item from spinner list. 
so for example as shown here in [image: gmail android app] if you select Sent then it will only have other elements shown in the spinner.

My Understanding says that it is a custom ActionView rather than using NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST with custom adapter.

Comment: Found the partial solution at this question [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11410028/android-custom-adapter-with-custom-spinner-drop-down-xml-layout-giving-error)

Answer (score 2):

If someone else is looking for the solution to this problem here it is,

Here is sample code which is written with the help of [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11410028/android-custom-adapter-with-custom-spinner-drop-down-xml-layout-giving-error)

use following code to create your adapter and join it to ActionBar List Navigation

```
ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);

    itemArr = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.array_spinner_items);
    items = toArrayList(itemArr, null);

    navigationAdapter = new CustomAdapter(this, R.layout.navigation_item_layout, items);
    actionBar.setListNavigationCallbacks(navigationAdapter, this);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
```

Extend `BaseAdapter` or `ArrayAdapter` and `implement SpinnerAdapter`

In your adapter override getDropdownView which is responsible for individual item view in dropdown 
and override getView which is responsible for the view appearing in the ActionBar

`public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter implements SpinnerAdapter {

```
    Context context;
    int textViewResourceId;
    ArrayList<String> arrayList;

    public CustomAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,  ArrayList<String> arrayList) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, arrayList);

        this.context = context;
        this.textViewResourceId = textViewResourceId;
        this.arrayList = arrayList;

    }

    @Override
     public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
       if (convertView == null)
       {
         LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
         //convertView = vi.inflate(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, null);
         convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.navigation_item_layout, null);
       }

       TextView textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.navigation_item);
       textView.setText(arrayList.get(position).toString());//after changing from ArrayList<String> to ArrayList<Object>

       if (position  == curitem) { 
          textView.setHeight(0);
      }
      else{
        textView.setHeight(60);
      }

       return convertView;
     }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if(convertView == null) {
            convertView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.navigation_item_layout, null);
        }
        TextView textview = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.navigation_item);
        textview.setText(itemArr[position].toUpperCase());
        textview.setTextColor(Color.RED);
        return convertView;
    }

}`
```

Here is the layout file for spinner item navigation_tem_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/navigation_item" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:padding="10dp" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to not provide the current entry in the navigation list, and just display it in the custom SpinnerAdapter in getView() method.

I just wrote a post with full source code, but my example uses static typed-arrays - you could change it to use a custom NavigationListItem class (or whatever you want to call it) and build a dynamic list per activity so that doesn't include the current one. You will need to be careful though as the spinner will try to select the first entry upon start, but you can display what you want in getView() as opposed to using the entry provided by position.

[dandar3.blogspot.com/2013/03/actionbarsherlock-custom-list-navigation.html](http://dandar3.blogspot.com/2013/03/actionbarsherlock-custom-list-navigation.html)