# How to add spinner to title bar of action-bar?

Tags: android

```
private void setTabNavigation(ActionBar bar){
    String[] actions = new String[] {
            "Bookmark",
            "Subscribe",
            "Share"
    };
    bar.removeAllTabs();
    bar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    bar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#a5a5a5")));
    bar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
       getBaseContext(),  
          android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, actions);
}
```

How can i add spinners to my `title bar` of action-bar? I get the small arrow besides my title-bar, but how would i add spinner to it and event-listener.

Comment: I believe that [this will help you](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13756713/gmail-android-app-like-actionview-spinner-navigation-mode-list)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are missing setting the

```
bar.setListNavigationCallbacks(adapter, mNavigationCallback);
```

You have a good example in the developer.android.com
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html